# Off-canvas меню

Tags: меню, transition, javascript, transform, css

Добрый вечер!

На досуге занимаюсь разработкой собственного сайта и возникли трудности в создании off-canvas меню. Структура страницы состоит из трёх блоков - "шапка", меню и содержимое.

Изначально меню видно. Ширина меню составляет 20% от ширины контейнера, ширина блока с содержимым - 80%.

Упрощённо, задача заключается в том, что при нажатии на кнопку "Меню", меню плавно смещается за край контейнера. В свою очередь блок содержимого плавно растягивается до 100% от ширины контейнера.

При повторном нажатии на кнопку "Меню", слева плавно выходит меню, которое занимает 20% от ширины контейнера. В свою очередь ширина блока с содержимым плавно уменьшается до 80%. Именно уменьшается, а не частично смещается за край контейнера. (именно это заставило писать своё решение).

Схематически это выглядит так:

[image: Off-canvas-2]

[image: Off-canvas-3]

[image: Off-canvas-1]

Появление/исчезновение меню я достиг за счёт css свойства "transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)". Проблема в том, что при смещении меню за край контейнера, блок содержимого хоть и растягивается до 100%, но "падает" вниз из за нехватки места. Понимаю, что за меню остались те самые 20% от ширины контейнера.

Как быть?

Буду очень Вам благодарен за помощь!

Код:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <header id="header">
      <a id="show-nav" href="#">Menu</a>
   </header>
   <nav class="visible" id="nav">
      Nav
   </nav>
   <main id="main" role="main">
      Main
   </main>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    max-width: 75em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
}

#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
#main {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    transition: transform 500ms ease 0s;
    background: gray;
}
#nav {
    background: green;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 500ms ease 0s;
}
#nav.visible {
    transform: none;
}

#main.large {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var nav = $("#nav");

$('#show-nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (nav.hasClass('visible')) {
        nav.removeClass('visible');
        $("#main").addClass('large');
    } else {
        nav.addClass('visible');
        $("#main").removeClass('large');
    }
});
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо, lampa! Работает как часы )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js:

```
$('#show-nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.container').toggleClass('large');
});
```

css:

```
#main {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: gray;
}
#nav {
    background: green;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.container.large #main {
    width: 100%;
}

.container.large #nav {
    width:0%;
}
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/LcNJ4/1/

Аж приятно отвечать на такой понятно расписанный вопрос, спасибо!)