# Как сделать шторы на мобильной версии?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать шторы на мобильной версии, используя `::before` и `::after`?

Сейчас у меня:

```
@media screen and (max-width:926px){ aside {display: none;} }
```

и:

```
<aside>
    <div class="top">
        <ul>
                <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Не пойму, как сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки выезжали шторы (aside) (к примеру, как ВКонтакте).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется off-canvas меню.
Здесь есть все наиболее популярные виды [off-canvas меню](http://codezona.com/off-canvas-menu.html).

Еще можно посмотреть ответ на [этом форуме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349210/javascript-off-canvas-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E).